# facebook "LIKE" button on Wordpress blog doesn't create a link on facebook?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, hyperlink, facebook-like

I set up the facebook like button on my blog and when I click "LIKE", on my facebook profile, it says "XXX (my name) likes Yeok-Rin « GOINGNOWHERE on raw.herobo.com."

Only problem is that at facebook recent activity page, it doesn't show the link, as shown here

---

[image: Example image]

---

I "liked" a random post and a post from my blog and the one below has a link (blue text with underline) while my post just comes out as a text.

raw.herobo.com/blog/  (again, i can only place one link yet) is my blog, and you can try clicking "LIKE" yourself.

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution for Like button (and other social platform buttons)

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=100&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This should go inside loop or You can use some globals, like $post if You need them

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed tutorial on how to integrate the Facebook Like Button with Wordpress on my blog here:

http://abecoffman.com/2011/advanced-wordpress-like-button-integration/

If you follow these steps the like button will post a link and an image into the users friend feed which is a lot more valuable than just a link.